# Dynamics CRM getting global OptionSet data using XrmServiceToolkit.Soap

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, entity, optionsettype, xrmservicetoolkit

When using Dynamics CRM 365, I would like to find a way to get the labels and values from a global OptionSet, using the Javascript library "XrmServiceToolkit" and the Soap method (we need it to be async).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found working:

Getting all the attributes of the OptionSet:

```
var myOptionSetData = XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.RetrieveAttributeMetadata('entity_logical_name_that_contains_a_field_with_the_optionset', 'optionset_logical_name', false);
```

Afterwards you can access the values and labels like so:

```
var last = myOptionSetData[0].OptionSet.Options.length - 1;
var vals = [];
var labels = [];

for (var idx = 0; idx <= last; idx++)
{
    vals.push(parseInt(myOptionSetData[0].OptionSet.Options[idx].Value));
    labels.push(myOptionSetData[0].OptionSet.Options[idx].Label.UserLocalizedLabel.Label)
}
```

Hope it helps someone.